# use variable in pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am new to jquery I have a simple html textarea and I want to count specific word in text area and show that count and also highlight that text too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   

    $(".text").on('input',function(){
    var a= $(".text").val();
    //var a="i m running";
     /*if(a==="nokia"){
 
 alert("nokia found");
    }
    else{
 alert("not found");
    }*/
     var pattern = /nokia/;
    var pattern1 = /samsung/;
    var pattern2 = /iphone/;
    var pattern3 = /qmobile/;
    //returns true or false...
    var exists = pattern.test(a);
    var exists1 = pattern1.test(a);
    var exists2 = pattern2.test(a);
    var exists3 = pattern3.test(a);
    if(exists){
    //true statement, do whatever
    //alert("nokia");
    $(".nokia").css("background-color", "green"); 
     }
     else{
       //false statement..do whatever
     //alert("not nokia");
       $(".nokia").css("background-color", "red");
      }
      if(exists1){
       //true statement, do whatever
       //alert("samsung found");
       $(".samsung").css("background-color", "green");
     }
    else{
     //false statement..do whatever
     // alert("not samsung found");
      $(".samsung").css("background-color", "red");
     }
     if(exists2){
     //true statement, do whatever
    //alert("samsung found");
     $(".iphone").css("background-color", "green");
    }
     else{
     //false statement..do whatever
     //alert("not samsung found");
      $(".iphone").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    if(exists3){
     //true statement, do whatever
     // alert("samsung found");
     $(".qmobile").css("background-color", "green");
    }
    else{
     //false statement..do whatever
    //alert("not samsung found");
    $(".qmobile").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    });
      counter = function() {
      var value = $('#text').val();

     if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);
        $('#totalChars').html(0);
        $('#charCount').html(0);
        $('#charCountNoSpace').html(0);
        return;
     }
      var regex = /\s+/gi;
      var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
     };
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keydown(counter);
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id='text' style="width: 50%;height: 20%;"  type="text" class="text"/></textarea>
<button name="click" class="btn"/>click</button>
<div id="result">
        Words: <span id="wordCount">0</span><br/>
</div>
<ul>

    <li class="nokia">nokia</li>
 <li class="samsung">samsung</li>
 <li class="iphone">iphone</li>
 <li class="qmobile">qmobile</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tried to tidy up your post and code a little, to stand you *some* chance of getting an answer. However, its not entirely clear what you're trying to do.... you want to count the words in the textarea, but then what do you want to do with highlighting words? What is the button supposed to do?

Comment: To make it clear, you have let's say a text like `Hello, this is a test, Hello, this is a test, Hello, this is a test` and then for example you want to count the number of `test` word appearances? And then highlight all `test` words in the textarea?

Comment: if i have a text area and i am writing some words in it. but i want to highlight that specific words  like nokia in text area how to do that